# Upper bound on logarithm, of a binomial quotient.

Tags: logarithms

What is the tighest upper and lower bounds for $\log{ (\binom{n}{n/2})}$?
I know that a naive upper bound would be $n \log{n}$ but is there any tighter bound? If so, how do I approach to solve this?

Comment: Stirling? ${}{}$

Comment: Does [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2929394/how-to-find-a-numerical-approximation-of-this-sum) help? (Only related related occurred in approach 0 on searching by one format)

Comment: @MaximilianJanisch probably I should do that.

Comment: @UmbQbify - That still leaves it at the same point. But as the post suggests, maybe Stirling would do.